# Multiple forks and IO:Pipe

Tags: perl, pipe

I am trying to build a program wich creates some forks and writes the results of the forks back to the main program. Thereby I try to use [`IO::Pipe`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Pipe.html)

```
sub ForkRequests {

  my $pipe = IO::Pipe->new();
  my $pid;

  foreach my $feature ( @features ) {

    if ( $pid = fork() ) {
      $pipe->reader();
      while ( <$pipe> ) {
        print $_. "\n";
      }
    }
    elsif ( defined $pid ) {

      #child
      $pipe->writer();

      #somecalculations [...]
      print $pipe $calcresults;
    }
  }
}
```

I got my code for doing a pipe from the module's documentation.

If i now try to execute, I get an error message

```
Can't locate object method "reader" via package "IO::Pipe::End" at lmtest3.pl line 56.
Can't locate object method "writer" via package "IO::Pipe::End" at lmtest3.pl line 63.
Can't locate object method "reader" via package "IO::Pipe::End" at lmtest3.pl line 56, <GEN0> line 1.
Can't locate object method "writer" via package "IO::Pipe::End" at lmtest3.pl line 63, <GEN0> line 1.
```

So, my code does not seem to initiate a pipe object, but an `IO::Pipe::End`.
So my question is, can anybody see the mistake in there? Why does it return the wrong object, and how would this be done correctly?

**EDIT**

I have some requests to some servers (most of the time 1 request to 7 ervers).
Those request names are saved in `@features`, and will be executed at the point of `#somecalculations`.

Because the server response is pretty slow, I want those requests to start in parallel. They all have to get back to the main program and print the reply to the console.

I tried this code

```
sub ForkRequests {

  my $i = 0;
  my @pipes;
  my $pid;

  foreach my $feature ( @features ) {

    @pipes[$i] = IO::Pipe->new();
    if ( $pid = fork() ) {
      @pipes[$i]->reader();
    }
    elsif ( defined $pid ) {

      #child
      @pipes[$i]->writer();

      # calculations
      my $w = @pipes[$i];
      print $w $calc;
      print $w "end\n";
    }

    $i++;
  }
}

if ( $pid == 1 ) {
  while ( 1 ) {
    foreach my $pipe ( @pipes ) {
      while ( <$pipe> ) {
        unless ( $_ == "end" ) {
          print $_. "\n";
        }
        else { last; }
      }
    }
  }
}
else {
  exit;
}

}
```

as said, to save those pipes, but I still got a problem in reading them, as the program exits before it gets answers.

Comment: When trying to pass data back and forth, I often think threads are a bit easier to work with. Is that an option here?

Comment: @Sobrique: In theory, yes. But the [documentation for `threads`](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html#WARNING) carries the warning *"The use of interpreter-based threads in perl is officially discouraged"*.

Comment: True, but I always thought that was more because of general misunderstanding of the threading paradigm in perl (e.g. how they're totally not lightweight) than because of any specific 'problem'. And for specific use cases (active IPC) they're quite handy.

Comment: @Sobrique: Maybe, but the big disadvantage they have for me is that there is no sharing of data without adding [`threads::shared`](https://metacpan.org/module/threads::shared) to what is already an emulation built into the perl executable. In any case I would rather not defy that official discouragement by going into how to use them in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are forking multiple child processes but trying to use the same pipe for all of them.

The `reader` method converts `$pipe` into an `IO::Pipe::End` object that you can read data from, so the first child is connected correctly. But you then call `reader` again on the same `$pipe`, and the error is thrown because it is no longer an object of the right class.

You simply need to create a new pipe for each child process:

```
sub fork_requests {

    for my $feature ( @features ) {

        my $pipe = IO::Pipe->new;
        my $pid;

        if ( $pid = fork ) {
            $pipe->reader;
            print while <$pipe>;
        }
        elsif ( defined $pid ) {
            $pipe->writer;
            # some calculations . . .
            print $pipe $calcresults;
            exit;
        }
    }

}
```

---

**Update**

Okay I think I understand what it is you need. This complete program should show you.

I have written `fork_requests` so that it expects a list of features as parameters, and I have written the child code so that it sleeps for two seconds to emulate the processing time and then simply prints the name of the feature.

The parent code stores all the pipes in an array, as I suggested, and prints the output from each of them in the order they were queued. All five child processes complete after two seconds, so the parent is suspended for that time and then prints the features originally passed in.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Pipe;

STDOUT->autoflush;

fork_requests('A' .. 'E');

sub fork_requests {

    my @pipes;

    for my $feature ( @_ ) {

        my $pipe = IO::Pipe->new;
        my $pid;

        if ( $pid = fork ) {
            $pipe->reader;
            push @pipes, $pipe;
        }
        elsif ( defined $pid ) {
            $pipe->writer;
            select $pipe;
            # some calculations . . .
            sleep 2;
            my $calcresults = $feature;
            print $calcresults, "\n";
            exit;
        }
    }

    for my $pipe ( @pipes ) {
      print while <$pipe>;
    }

}
```

**output**

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

Comment: if i create the pipe inside the for Loop, wouldn't that overwrite my old pipe?
I want to run 5 forks parallel, so all 5 Need to write back to the same pipe

Comment: You can't read from multiple child processes at the same time on the same pipe. Pipes can have only two ends. It may be that you need to save the handles in an array before reading from them, but you don't say enough about your application to be able to tell.

Comment: i'm not sure which part you are missing, so i hope my edit will clean this out. if not, please tell me which Information is desired

Comment: @chenino: I've added a working program that works as I described. Let me know if it does what you need.

Comment: if i dont get this code wrong, it still executes each fork after another, and reads after that, or am i wrong?

Comment: @chenino: Correct. If the parent read the data from the first pipe before starting the second child then it would be waiting for each child to complete before starting another, which defeats the point of the forking.  As it is, it starts all children in a fraction of a second, som that they all run in parallel, and then prints all return data as it becomes available.

Comment: Presumably you could use `select` to async read from the pipes, but doing it this way means you retrieve the results in a defined order, which is often useful.

Comment: @Sobrique: `select` is for output streams. Here you would just use `<$pipes[$i]>` as appropriate. With more code you could collect the return data in the order that the child processes completed. But, as you say, I suspect that a fixed order is more useful, and it is likely that one child's results are of no use without all the rest. Regardless, the goal of running the OP's server requests in parallel has been accomplished.

Comment: @sobrique well, i dont need an specific order, i just Need to not 2 values from the child processes.

Comment: @borodin as those calls are slow, those should be executed parallel. the main process just reads the values they returned. so, i am grateful for your help, but as you say, it defeats why i am forking.  i would Need an Approach to start those simualtaeniously and read them "as they come"

Comment: @chenino: Please understand ***the child processes are being started simultaneously***. Also, the output completes as soon as the last child process has finished. Note that in my example code, each child process is sleeping for two seconds, yet the parent process delays for only two seconds because they are running in parallel. I siggest you run the program I have written and experiment with it yourself.

Comment: Indeed - the `fork`ed bit is run in parallel, and the "main" bit moves on to start reading input immediately after _starting_ the children.

Comment: @Sobrique: Yes. I thought I said that :)  The *first* `for` loop starts all the children, and the second `for` loop prints their output.

Comment: I was thinking of a more general case - I like `Thread::Queue` for task dispatching when threading. `fork` is a different paradigm though, so I'm still building my understanding.

Comment: @chenino: As you said yourself, *" it still executes each fork after another, and reads after that"* which is exactly what you want

Comment: @Sobrique: Maybe, but [`Thread::Queue`](https://metacpan.org/module/Thread::Queue) just uses [`threads`](https://metacpan.org/module/threads) and [`threads::shared`](https://metacpan.org/module/threads::shared) under the hood, but makes it all seem a lot less messy than it really is. You won't learn the basic principles if you stick to employing convenience modules.

Comment: @Borodin : I think i got it now, at least after fitting in my program is works as supposed. Thank you very much !